# loop generate plots for variables in a data frame

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, boxplot

So I have a data frame, set up a bit like this:

```
Sample V1  V2 V3  Group1 Group2
bob    12  32  12  G1      G2
susan  43  23  54  G2      G2
mary   23  65  34  G1      G2
```

I am able to do a grouped boxplot of each variable (V1, V2, V3) individually, grouped by Group1 and Group2 variables, but my real dataset has WAY more variables, and will be tedious to code individually. Is there a way that I can loop the process, and automate plot generation and export? For loops are still a bit of an obscure topic for me.

Here is the code I use to generate an individual plot:

```
png(filename= "filename.jpg")
ggplot(aes(y=data$V1, x=data$Group1, fill=data$Group2), data=data) + geomboxplot()
dev.off()
```

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? What have you tried? There are several approaches, partly depending on your data. You could transform your data to long format and either use facets or a split/lapply approach. Or loop over the needed columns to generate the plot, for instance by using aes_string.

Comment: I can imagine how you could use a for loop to call individual columns of the data frame that contain variables (V1, V2, etc) but I don't know how to specify the grouping variables (Group1, Group2), and keep those from changing in the loop. I'm really unfamiliar with writing loops and the syntax.

Comment: I think a facet plot might be what OP is looking for. melt those vars into a single var and then facet on that. To busy at the moment to code it, but would not be difficult. Have to look at reshape2 to do the melt.

Comment: `aes` looks for variables inside `data`. If you want to avoid some nasty surprises, you'll never use `$` inside `aes`. E.g., in this example `aes(y=V1, x=Group1, fill=Group2)` is correct syntax.

Comment: Great, I didn't know that about `aes`. Thanks for the warning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are several approaches for you. I'm guessing there is a duplicate, but if you're just starting out it's not always easy to apply those answers to your data.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
###create some data
set.seed(100)
n = 500

dat <- data.frame(sample = sample(LETTERS[1:10],n,T),
                  V1 = sample(50,n,T),
                  V2 = sample(50,n,T),
                  V3 = sample(50,n,T),
                  Group1 = paste0("G",sample(3,n,T)),
                  Group2 = paste0("G",sample(5,n,T)))
```

approach 1: melt and facet

```
dat_m <- melt(dat,measure.vars = c("V1","V2","V3"))

p1 <- ggplot(dat_m, aes(x = Group1,y = value,fill = Group2))+
  geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~variable)
p1
```

[image]

As you can see, this is not feasible when you have too many grouping variables.

approach 2: different plots/images per variable, still using the long data. I have split the long data by variable, and created a plot for each chunk. The current code plots to the console; file-saving code is commented out.

```
lapply(split(dat_m, dat_m$variable), function(chunk){
  myfilename <- sprintf("plot_%s.png", unique(chunk$variable))

  p <- ggplot(chunk, aes(x = Group1,y = value,fill = Group2)) +
    geom_boxplot() + labs(title = myfilename)
  p
#   #png(filename = myfilename)
#   print(p)
#   dev.off()

})
```

And a third approach is to use the strings of columns you're interested in:

```
#vector of columns you want to plot
mycols <- c("V1","V2","V3")

#plotting for each column. Not that I've put the 'fixed' variable
#inside aes in the main call to ggplot, and the 'varying' variable
#inside aes_string in the call to boxplot

lapply(mycols, function(cc){
  myfilename <- sprintf("plot_%s.png",cc)
  p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = Group1,fill = Group2)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes_string(y = cc)) + labs(title = myfilename)
  p
  #   #png(filename = myfilename)
  #   print(p)
  #   dev.off()
})
```

Comment: Great! Thank you, the lapply function is precisely what I was struggling to write myself. The joys of a biologist trying to learn coding. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have got the loop to work for creating the plots in R studio, but there somehow the  `png()` function doesn't seem to be working- it only creates blank images when I add that part of the code back in. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should use 'print(p)'. Sorry, I didn't test that part of the code. Have edited my answer.

Comment: If it worked, could you accept the answer? Keeps others from spending time on it.